# Can any one explain the asserTrue why it is failed?

Tags: java, selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I am new to Selenium and Java.

I have tried the below to compare the field value of last name to the one which i supplied.

```
String lastname=selenium.getValue("//*[@id='lastName']");
System.out.println(lastname);
assertTrue (lastname == "xxx");
```

It is keep on failing.

Just literally tried to change the last line with help of Eclipse (just trial and error)

```
assertTrue("lastname.equals("xxx"));
```

It is working fine... Why it is failed in first case? == is not allowed to compare strings?

Comment: This has to be the most common gotcha in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `==` checks for same object `.equals` checks for the same value.

More info in [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`equals` function checks the actual contents of the `lastname`. `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

Comment: More Info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 0):

You must use equals() to compare strings with Java, as you guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually comparing *pointers* (or really reference equality) when you use `==` with strings. In other words you're testing if two objects are the same, rather than the *content* of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing equality of string ,We Use equals() Method. There are two ways of comparison in java. One is "==" operator and another "equals()" method .  "==" compares the reference value of string object whereas equals() method is present in the java.lang.Object class. This method compares content of the string object.